# Android Arduino and Bluetooth

Tags: android, html, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino

I am doing my project on Android and Arduino ,i am able to send the message from Android to Arduino via bluetooth ,but am struggling to get the message from Arduino to Android via bluetooth.Please help to complete the project.Thank you in advance

Receiving code :

private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

```
    private boolean bStop = false;
    private Thread t;

    public ReadInput() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
        t.start();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return t.isAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
            while (!bStop) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    int i = 0;
                    /*
                     * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                     */
                    for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                    }
                    final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);

                    /*
                     * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
                     */

                    if (chkReceiveText.isChecked()) {
                        mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mTxtReceive.append(strInput);
                                //Uncomment below for testing
                                //mTxtReceive.append("\n");
                                //mTxtReceive.append("Chars: " + strInput.length() + " Lines: " + mTxtReceive.getLineCount() + "\n");

                                int txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                                if (txtLength > mMaxChars) {
                                    mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);
                                }

                                if (chkScroll.isChecked()) { // Scroll only if this is checked
                                    scrollView.post(new Runnable() { // Snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/1287554
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void stop() {
        bStop = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

        private boolean bStop = false;
        private Thread t;

        public ReadInput() {
            t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
            t.start();
        }  
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return t.isAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;

Comment: try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i = 0;
                        /*

Comment: for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);

      /*
       * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
       */

                        if (chkReceiveText.isChecked()) {
                            mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                             mTxtReceive.append(strInput);

Comment: nt txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                                    if (txtLength > mMaxChars) {
         mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);
                                    }

           if (chkScroll.isChecked()) { // Scroll only if this is checked
      scrollView.post(new Runnable() { // Snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/1287554
                                            @Override
    public void run()                                           scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
           }
        });
   }

Comment: });
                        }

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

Comment: You should edit the question and add code there. Don't add it in the comments. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try putting rx of arduino to tx of bluetooth module and tx of bluetooth module to rx of arduino. Which arduino are you using and what is the bluetooth module you are using? Is it HC05H?

Also show your code if possible.

Comment: Arduino UNO and Bluetooth Module is HC05

Comment: The message is sending from Arduino but am not able to display it on Android app.This is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just using `Serial.print("");` you can send Strings to and from Arduino to Android. For more information, [refer to this link](https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/).

Comment: yes sir, I have already tried this example and downloaded the code from github but it does not display anything.

Comment: sir,can u please the share the function that receive the message from arduino

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar project using Bluetooth and Arduino and I have a github with a fully working code: https://github.com/Primaelq/Mapping-Robot/blob/master/Companion%20App/Eye-BotCompanionApp/app/src/main/java/studio/eye/a/eye_botcompanionapp/BluetoothService.java This is the BluetoothService class, you should take a look at the connected thread method. Feel free to use any of the code or ask any questions.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Ok sir,I will check it once.