# imageview visibility by onclick button

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I'm currently working on an app where I want to add a button to toggle visibility on a certain ImageView. Beforehand, there are 3 GraphViews on my UI, and when visibility is toggled, ImageView will overlap the two graphs below. However, when I run the app, the 'app has stopped' 
The btndiag button causes the error

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "TUP-MainActivity";
private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default
private UUID mDeviceUUID;
private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
private ReadInput mReadThread = null;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private boolean mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = false;

// All controls here
private TextView mTxtReceive;
private Button mBtnDisconnect;
private Button mBtnStart;
private GraphView1 graphView1;
private GraphView2 graphView2;
private GraphView3 graphView3;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Button btnDiag;
private ImageView imgDiag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    graphView1 = (GraphView1) findViewById(R.id.graph_view1);
    graphView2 = (GraphView2) findViewById(R.id.graph_view2);
    graphView3 = (GraphView3) findViewById(R.id.graph_view3);



    ActivityHelper.initialize(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

    mDevice = b.getParcelable(Homescreen.DEVICE_EXTRA);
    mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(Homescreen.DEVICE_UUID));
    mMaxChars = b.getInt(Homescreen.BUFFER_SIZE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Ready");

    mBtnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnect);
    mBtnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnDiag = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btDiag);


    mTxtReceive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mTxtReceive.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());



    mBtnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = true;
            new DisConnectBT().execute();
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mBTSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
            mConnectedThread.write("B");
        }
    });


    mBtnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mBTSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
            mConnectedThread.write("A");
        }
});

    btnDiag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnDiag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    imgDiag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

        }
    });
}

private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

    private boolean bStop = false;
    private Thread t;

    public ReadInput() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
        t.start();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return t.isAlive();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        InputStream inputStream;
                 try {
            inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
            while (!bStop) {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    int i = 0;
                    /*
                     * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                     */
                    for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                    }
                    final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);


                    mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            String[] items = strInput.split("\\*");


                            for (String item : items )
                            {
                                if(item.length() == 12){

                                    try{
                                        //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5;
                                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(item.substring(1, 3));
                                        ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edg_image);
                                        if ( value <= 77) {
                                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
                                        }
                                        else if ( value <= 80 && value >=78) {
                                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.center);
                                        }
                                        else if ( value >= 81 ){
                                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                                        }
                                        System.out.println("acc = " + value);
                                       }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
                                        System.out.println("Not an integer");
                                       }

                                    try{


                                        //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5;
                                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(item.substring(3, 6));
                                        System.out.println("ecg = "+ value);
                                        graphView1.plotProcedure1(value);



                                    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
                                        System.out.println("Not an integer");

                                    }

                                    try{
                                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(item.substring(6, 9));
                                        System.out.println("eda = "+ value);
                                        graphView2.plotProcedure2(value);
                                    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
                                        System.out.println("Not an integer");
                                    }

                                    try{
                                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(item.substring(9, 12));
                                        System.out.println("emg = "+ value);
                                        graphView3.plotProcedure3(value);
                                    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
                                        System.out.println("Not an integer");


                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    });

                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void stop() {
        bStop = true;
    }
}

private class DisConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (mReadThread != null) {
            mReadThread.stop();
            while (mReadThread.isRunning())
                ; // Wait until it stops
            mReadThread = null;

        }
        try {
            mBTSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
        if (mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}


private void msg(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mBTSocket != null && mIsBluetoothConnected) {
        new DisConnectBT().execute();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
        new ConnectBT().execute();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
    super.onResume();

};


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Hold on", "Connecting");// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {

        try {
            if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                mBTSocket.connect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to connect to device
            e.printStackTrace();
            mConnectSuccessful = false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to device. Is it a Serial device? Also check if the UUID is correct in the settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            msg("Connected to device");
            mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
            mReadThread = new ReadInput(); // Kick off input reader
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}


//create new class for connect thread
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket mBTSocket) {
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpOut = mBTSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    //write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
}
}
```

logcat error

```
01-04 07:04:08.467 22700-22700/com.tup.tup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: com.tup.tup, PID: 22700
                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tup.tup/com.tup.tup.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                             at com.tup.tup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Add proper code like layout and java file. we can't help with magic

Comment: I need to see the code...you are probably not properly initializing the imageview

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Logcat output ?

Comment: i uploaded the logcat error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.tup.tup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)

Comment: I don't have the number lines, but you are accessing to a null reference in the line 82 of MainActivity

Comment: What should i do with the null reference?im quiet new to this error