# How to add bluetooth receive code to my code?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Im almost getting to the end of my Sound bar project (2 arduinos, relays, digital potentiometers, leds, i2c, bluetooth and ir remote, diy amplifier,...) and I`m stuck.

This is my first time using android studio and things are becoming so hard for me.

I created an app with a few buttons, switch, sliders and dropdown menu that connects to bluetooth module and sends values to my arduino.

Now I need to add a script that would receive values that arduino is sending (got arduino code done), and would eventualy set buttons clickable/unclickable and set slider positions depending on values being received thru bluetooth.

Can somebody please show me the way to read values from bluetooth and store them in integer or something so that buttons could be disabled and enabled with if(integer=x); statements.

I will post my java code (App is almost done, excepet for sliders and this bluetooth receive part) and I will post the code I came with so far...

I`m going nuts on this one.

Thank you for help :)

```
package com.interface80.soundbarcontrol;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.icu.text.Transliterator;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class Remote extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "BlueTest5-Controlling";
    private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default//change this to string..........
    private UUID mDeviceUUID;
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
    private ReadInput mReadThread = null;

    private boolean mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = false;
    private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
    private int mLastSpinnerPosition = 0;



    private Button mBtnDisconnect;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    final static String on="92";//on
    final static String off="79";//off
    final static String subon="10";//subon
    final static String suboff="15";//suboff
    final static String zero="20";//zeroDB
    final static String six="25";//sixDB
    final static String twelwe="30";//twelweDB
    final static String userBoost="40";
    final static String softBoost="45";
    final static String normalBoost="50";
    final static String hardBoost="55";
    final static String overloadOn="60";
    final static String overloadOff="65";
    Switch toggle; //outside oncreate



    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Button btnon,btnoff, btnsubon, btnsuboff, btnzero, btnsix, btntwelwe;
    Switch overloadSwitch;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remote);
        Spinner spinnerPresets = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPresets);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPresets = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Remote.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayPresets));
        adapterPresets.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerPresets.setAdapter(adapterPresets);
        spinnerPresets.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        ActivityHelper.initialize(this);
        // mBtnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnect);
        btnon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on);
        btnoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);
        btnsubon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subon);
        btnsuboff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suboff);
        btnzero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
        btnsix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        btntwelwe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twelwe);
        overloadSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.overloadSwitch);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        mDevice = b.getParcelable(MainActivity.DEVICE_EXTRA);
        mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(MainActivity.DEVICE_UUID));
        mMaxChars = b.getInt(MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Ready");


        btnon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(on.getBytes());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(off.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnsubon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(subon.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnsuboff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(suboff.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnzero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(zero.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnsix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(six.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btntwelwe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(twelwe.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }




@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (mLastSpinnerPosition == position)
            {
                return;
            }
        mLastSpinnerPosition = position;
            if (0 == position) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Boost controlled by user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnzero.setEnabled(true);
                btnsix.setEnabled(true);
                btntwelwe.setEnabled(true);

                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(userBoost.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return; //do nothing
            }
            if (1 == position) {
                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(softBoost.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "DynaBoost control.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnzero.setEnabled(false);
                btnsix.setEnabled(false);
                btntwelwe.setEnabled(false);
                return; //do nothing
            }
            if (2 == position) {
                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(normalBoost.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "DynaBoost control.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnzero.setEnabled(false);
                btnsix.setEnabled(false);
                btntwelwe.setEnabled(false);
                return; //do nothing
            }
            if (3 == position) {
                try {
                    mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(hardBoost.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "DynaBoost control.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnzero.setEnabled(false);
                btnsix.setEnabled(false);
                btntwelwe.setEnabled(false);
                return; //do nothing
            }
        }






    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

        private boolean bStop = false;
        private Thread t;

        public ReadInput() {
            t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
            t.start();
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return t.isAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i = 0;
                        /*
                         * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                         */
                        for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);

                        /*
                         * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
                         */



                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void stop() {
            bStop = true;
        }

    }

    private class DisConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {//cant inderstand these dotss

            if (mReadThread != null) {
                mReadThread.stop();
                while (mReadThread.isRunning())
                    ; // Wait until it stops
                mReadThread = null;

            }

            try {
                mBTSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
            if (mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect) {
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mBTSocket != null && mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new DisConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new ConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Remote.this, "", "Connecting");// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {

            try {
                if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                    mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    mBTSocket.connect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// Unable to connect to device`
                // e.printStackTrace();
                mConnectSuccessful = false;



            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect.Please turn on Sound bar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Connected to Sound bar");
                mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
                mReadThread = new ReadInput(); // Kick off input reader
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void toggle( View View) //outside oncreate
    {
        if( overloadSwitch.isChecked() ){
            try {
                mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(overloadOn.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return; //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(overloadOff.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return; //do nothing

        }
    }
    }
```

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int BTvalue = buffer;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }
```

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I spent late night yesterday with no succes. Angry and frustrated I went to bed. Today I found out that none of the codes I was trying didn`t work, because code was already there. Reading and writing to string. Just used the string and done :)