# How to get inputStream (bluetooth) to write/ show properly

Tags: java, android, arduino, inputstream

Arduino is sending values via hc05 module to android. Values from 0 to 9, 90, 92, 50, 55, ... etc, values from 100 to 350 and from 400 to 650.
Android reads and writes those values in textbox (for debugging purposes). Then I controll UI animations with if statements.

90% android reads these values right, but sometimes it reads 7 instead on 77 for example, basicly it chops first number off. I found this out by sending 7777 number to it and it read it as 777.
Values between 0 and 9 (single number) always show as it should.
If I play with Thread.sleep(millis) I get different results, but 50millis is the best, but not error free. I have a feeling that code gets sent in the time when thread is sleeping and this cuts the first nubmer off.

Bellow I will post part of my java code. This is the part where inputStream is received, then actions are executed with if statements. I added one if statement to show example. I shaved my code as much as I could because it`s big and messy.

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(demandValues.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i = 0;
                        /*
                         * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                         */
                        for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                        TextView BTtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BTtext);
                        BTtext.setText(strInput);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            
                                if (BTtext.getText().toString().equals("11"))
                                {
                                    overloadSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.overloadSwitch);
                                    overloadSwitch.setChecked(false);
                                    btntwelwe.setEnabled(false);


                                }
                        });
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(50);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Best thing would be if I could make it to recognize the starting character and ending character.
Then I would program arduino to send <77> for example and < would be the trigger to start writing the value to textbox and > to stop then next < would clear the textbox for new code and so on...
That way I would be able to remove delays in arduino I set when sending multiple codes one after another. I have that delay set at 100ms, I played with it and 100 works the best.
What can I do with my code to rectify the problem.

I`m new to java and had come far with my project combining codes from examples from internet and combining them together, but I am stuck here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT SOLVED!

I don`t know java, but I know logic.
I changed:

if (inputStream.available() > 0)

to:

if (inputStream.available() > 2)

Now it only reads if input stream is at least 3 bytes.

Then I changed my command values so they are all 3 bytes.
I added nines. So for example 1 is now 991 and 12 is now 912...
Some my laugh at my solution, but it works like a charm, no additional code needed.