# Cannot get the value from sharedPrefenced

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey guys again with my question
So as in the title, my apps need data from another activity using sharedPreferenced
So far so good I got the data I store **WHEN** I click the button but when i tried to get the data on the onCreate it just crashing with this error code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.aplikasirevisi, PID: 28272
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.aplikasirevisi/com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.onCreate(Information.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28272 SIG: 9
```

It says it's null but when I click the button it's giving me the data though 

Here is my code:
**Information.Java**

```
package com.test.aplikasirevisi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class Information extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    TextView name;
    TextView phonenum;
    TextView highest;
    TextView lowest;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String PhoneNum = "phonenumKey";
    public static final String Highest = "highestKey";
    public static final String Lowest = "lowestKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(PhoneNum)) {
            phonenum.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PhoneNum, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
        }
    }
    public void Save(View view) {
        String n = name.getText().toString();
        String p = phonenum.getText().toString();
        String h = highest.getText().toString();
        String l = lowest.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(PhoneNum, p);
        editor.putString(Highest, h);
        editor.putString(Lowest, l);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void clear(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        phonenum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNum);
        highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
        lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);
        name.setText("");
        phonenum.setText("");
        highest.setText("");
        lowest.setText("");
    }
    public void Get(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        phonenum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNum);
        highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
        lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(PhoneNum)) {
            phonenum.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PhoneNum, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
        }
    }

}
```

**MonitoringScreen.Java**

```
package com.test.aplikasirevisi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.Highest;
import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.Lowest;
import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.mypreference;


public class MonitoringScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BlueTest5-MainActivity";
    private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default
    private UUID mDeviceUUID;
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
    private ReadInput mReadThread = null;
    TextView highest;
    TextView lowest;
    private boolean mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = false;

    private TextView mTxtReceive;
    private Button mBtnClearInput;
    private Button mBtnGetBPM;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private CheckBox chkScroll;
    private CheckBox chkReceiveText;


    private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;

    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring_screen);
        ActivityHelper.initialize(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        mDevice = b.getParcelable(MainActivity.DEVICE_EXTRA);
        mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(MainActivity.DEVICE_UUID));
        mMaxChars = b.getInt(MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Ready");
        mTxtReceive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReceive);
        chkScroll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkScroll);
        chkReceiveText = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkReceiveText);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.viewScroll);
        mBtnClearInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearInput);
        mBtnGetBPM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnGetBPM);
        mTxtReceive.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        mBtnClearInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mTxtReceive.setText("");
            }
        });
        mBtnGetBPM.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
                lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
                    highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
                }
                if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
                    lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private class ReadInput implements  Runnable{
        private boolean bStop = false;
        private Thread t;

        public ReadInput() {
            t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
            t.start();
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return t.isAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i;
                        /*
                         * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                         */
                        for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                        String getHi = null;


                        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
                            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
                            getHi=highest.getText().toString();
                        }
                        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
                            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
                        }
                        int hi = Integer.parseInt(getHi);

                        /*
                         * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
                         */

                        if (chkReceiveText.isChecked()) {
                            mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    int data = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
                                    mTxtReceive.append(strInput);

                                    int txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                                    if(txtLength > mMaxChars){
                                        mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "text longer than allowed:" + mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars));
                                        Log.d(TAG, strInput);
                                        if(data > hi){
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (chkScroll.isChecked()) { // Scroll only if this is checked
                                        scrollView.post(new Runnable() { // Snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/1287554
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void stop() {
            bStop = true;
        }

    }
    private class DisConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (mReadThread != null) {
                mReadThread.stop();
                while (mReadThread.isRunning())
                    ; // Wait until it stops
                mReadThread = null;

            }

            try {
                mBTSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
            if (mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect) {
                finish();
            }
        }

    }
    private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mBTSocket != null && mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new DisConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new ConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MonitoringScreen.this, "Hold on", "Connecting");// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {

            try {
                if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                    mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    mBTSocket.connect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// Unable to connect to device
                e.printStackTrace();
                mConnectSuccessful = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to device. Is it a Serial device? Also check if the UUID is correct in the settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Connected to device");
                mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
                mReadThread = new ReadInput(); // Kick off input reader
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I tried to automatically get the Highest bpm dan Lowest bpm but it spans the same error so I'm in a pickle now so if anyone can help with it dan fast I'll be grateful for that. And sorry for my English it's not my first language so I can't express it really well.

Comment: Read your error message, your TextView is null,. in your `Information.Java` activity, you haven't assigned the variable `name` to anything.

Comment: About that, I tried this tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial and they didn't assigned the variable name to anything and it works so i'm little bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextView` in your `Information.Java` are not assigned to anything within your `onCreate` method before you try calling the setText method. This is what the error is complaining about.

Your assignments are in the `clear(View view)` method for some reason.... they should be in the `onCreate` method.

i.e move

```
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        phonenum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNum);
        highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
        lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);
```

out of the `clear` and `get` methods and into the `onCreate` method like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        phonenum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNum);
        highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
        lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(PhoneNum)) {
            phonenum.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PhoneNum, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: wait that's the problem. Oh omg, I'm so stupid. well I'll try it later it's a stress full day today