# Changing String from buffer to int

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So another one from the same code with another problem.

here is the code

```
package com.test.aplikasirevisi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.Highest;
import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.Lowest;
import static com.test.aplikasirevisi.Information.mypreference;


public class MonitoringScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BlueTest5-MainActivity";
    private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default
    private UUID mDeviceUUID;
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
    private ReadInput mReadThread = null;
    TextView highest;
    TextView lowest;
    private boolean mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = false;

    private TextView mTxtReceive;
    private Button mBtnClearInput;
    private Button mBtnGetBPM;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private CheckBox chkScroll;
    private CheckBox chkReceiveText;


    private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;

    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring_screen);
        ActivityHelper.initialize(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        mDevice = b.getParcelable(MainActivity.DEVICE_EXTRA);
        mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(MainActivity.DEVICE_UUID));
        mMaxChars = b.getInt(MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Ready");
        mTxtReceive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReceive);
        chkScroll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkScroll);
        chkReceiveText = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkReceiveText);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.viewScroll);
        mBtnClearInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearInput);
        mBtnGetBPM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnGetBPM);
        mTxtReceive.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        highest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHighest);
        lowest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLowest);
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
        }
        mBtnClearInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mTxtReceive.setText("");
            }
        });
        
    }
    private class ReadInput implements  Runnable{
        private boolean bStop = false;
        private Thread t;

        public ReadInput() {
            t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
            t.start();
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return t.isAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i;
                        /*
                         * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                         */
                        for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                        String getHi = null;


                        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Highest)) {
                            highest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Highest, ""));
                            getHi=highest.getText().toString();
                        }
                        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Lowest)) {
                            lowest.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Lowest, ""));
                        }
                        int hi = Integer.parseInt(getHi);

                        /*
                         * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
                         */

                        if (chkReceiveText.isChecked()) {
                            mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtReceive.append(strInput);
                                    System.out.println(strInput);
                                    if(data < hi){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "succes");
                                    }
                                    int txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                                    if(txtLength > mMaxChars){
                                        mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "text longer than allowed:" + mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars));

                                    }

                                    if (chkScroll.isChecked()) { // Scroll only if this is checked
                                        scrollView.post(new Runnable() { // Snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/1287554
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void stop() {
            bStop = true;
        }

    }
    private class DisConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (mReadThread != null) {
                mReadThread.stop();
                while (mReadThread.isRunning())
                    ; // Wait until it stops
                mReadThread = null;

            }

            try {
                mBTSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
            if (mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect) {
                finish();
            }
        }

    }
    private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mBTSocket != null && mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new DisConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new ConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MonitoringScreen.this, "Hold on", "Connecting");// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {

            try {
                if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                    mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    mBTSocket.connect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// Unable to connect to device
                e.printStackTrace();
                mConnectSuccessful = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to device. Is it a Serial device? Also check if the UUID is correct in the settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Connected to device");
                mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
                mReadThread = new ReadInput(); // Kick off input reader
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

i want to change the String to int from this part:

```
final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);
```

so i can use it on this part :

```
 if(data < hi){
 Log.d(TAG, "succes");
 }
```

i tried to use

```
int data = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
```

but well of course it span error because its string buffer and only the first one is changed
so how do i solve this prob?if any one can help

I already tried using arraylist but still error

Here is the error code :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.aplikasirevisi, PID: 21905
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "40
    "
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.test.aplikasirevisi.MonitoringScreen$ReadInput$1.run(MonitoringScreen.java:152)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21905 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you what is wrong. Your input appears to be `"40` and `"` is not a numeric character. You need make sure your inputted strings are numeric OR you need to extract the numeric component from the string BEFORE attempting to convert it into an integer. You could try `new String(buffer, 1, i)` if the character at index 0 is always the double quote character.

**UPDATE**:

Based on your last comment posted here, you need to initialize your `strInput` as follows (This is an example):

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[5];
    bytes[0] = 49; // this is the ASCII value of the number "1"
    bytes[1] = '\u0000'; // These are null characters
    bytes[2] = '\u0000';
    bytes[3] = '\u0000';
    bytes[4] = '\u0000';

    String temp = new String(bytes); // convert the byte array to String
    String str = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('\u0000')); // parse the numeric contents
    System.out.println(str); // You should see "1" printed out
    int number = Integer.parseInt(str); // Because I parsed the numeric contents, it is safe to convert the String to a number.
```

Comment: tried it still same

Comment: @WhiliamsThunardy what is the entire contents of `buffer` before you attempt to parse it?

Comment: it's from sensor arduino

Comment: @WhiliamsThunardy what I meant was for you to print out to console the `strInput` right above `String getHi = null;` so you can see what is its contents. This should've been part of your own debugging.

Comment: i don't get it but aftre tried what u suggest it came out like this now 
`135
    ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`
it supposed to print just 135

Comment: i get the answer you provide i tried it but still spawn out like this
`����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������'

Comment: You can remove the `System.out.print`. The important thing is knowing that not all 256 bytes in the buffer are initialized to some numeric value. You need to parse the buffer an extract the values from the index of the first numeric byte up to the first index of those weird characters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: okay i tried it but when i parse it came out the same error
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Input Thread
    Process: com.test.aplikasirevisi, PID: 22710
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "152
    "
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.test.aplikasirevisi.MonitoringScreen$ReadInput.run(MonitoringScreen.java:140)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
E/RtgSchedManager: endActivityTransaction: margin state not match`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239746/discussion-between-whiliams-thunardy-and-hfontanez).