# Android read data via BT from Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

I'm having a problem with the code for my Arduiino.

I can send and receive datum with `bluetooth`, but I want to print the incoming data on the label.

For example, when `X` arrives, the label is `123`.

`Arduino` sends `X` code, but `Android` doesn't take `X` code.

If I am getting `X` code from `Arduino`, how can `Android` be delivered?

See my source code below:

```
    public class MonitoringScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default
    private UUID mDeviceUUID;
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
    private ReadInput mReadThread = null;

    private boolean mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect = false;

    private TextView mTxtReceive;
    private Button mBtnClearInput;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private CheckBox chkScroll;
    private CheckBox chkReceiveText;
    private Button sagup;
    private Button sagdown;
    private Button solup;
    private Button soldown;
    private Button modulekle;
    private Button modulcikar;
    private Button kalibrasyon;
    private ImageButton hakkinda;

    private TextView durum;

    private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;

    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    int loopDelay = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring_screen);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ActivityHelper.initialize(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        mDevice = b.getParcelable(MainActivity.DEVICE_EXTRA);
        mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(MainActivity.DEVICE_UUID));
        mMaxChars = b.getInt(MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Ready");
        mTxtReceive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReceive);
        chkScroll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkScroll);
        chkReceiveText = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkReceiveText);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.viewScroll);
        mBtnClearInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearInput);
        sagup = findViewById(R.id.sagup);
        sagdown = findViewById(R.id.sagdown);
        solup = findViewById(R.id.solup);
        soldown = findViewById(R.id.soldown);
        modulekle = findViewById(R.id.modulekle);
        modulcikar = findViewById(R.id.modulcikar);
        kalibrasyon = findViewById(R.id.kalibrasyon);
        hakkinda = findViewById(R.id.useinfo);
        durum=findViewById(R.id.sistembilgisi);
        mTxtReceive.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


        sagup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("0");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        sagdown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("1");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        solup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("2");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        soldown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("3");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        modulekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("4");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        modulcikar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("5");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        kalibrasyon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("8");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });

        hakkinda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = ("X");
                SendInput sendInput = new SendInput();
                sendInput.send(msg);
            }
        });


        mBtnClearInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mTxtReceive.setText("");
            }
        });

      }

    private class SendInput {
        InputStream inputStream;
        OutputStream outputStream;
        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void send(String message) {
            if(outputStream==null){
                try {
                    outputStream = mBTSocket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Hata !!!", "In onResume(), giriş ve çıkış akışı oluşturma başarısız oldu:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "...Gönderilecek veriler: " + message + "...");

            byte[] msgBuffer = (message+ " ").getBytes();
            try {
                outputStream.write(msgBuffer);
                Log.e(TAG, "Int" + Arrays.toString(msgBuffer));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Hata verisi gönderme: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
            }
        }
    }
    private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

        private boolean bStop = false;
        private Thread t;

        public ReadInput() {
            t = new Thread(this, "Gelen veri");
            t.start();
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return t.isAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
                while (!bStop) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        inputStream.read(buffer);
                        int i = 0;
                        /*
                         * This is needed because new String(buffer) is taking the entire buffer i.e. 256 chars on Android 2.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843462/1287554
                         */
                        for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                        }
                        final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);

                        /*
                         * If checked then receive text, better design would probably be to stop thread if unchecked and free resources, but this is a quick fix
                         */

                        if (chkReceiveText.isChecked()) {
                            mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mTxtReceive.append(strInput);

                                    int txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                                    if(txtLength > mMaxChars){
                                        mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);

                                    }

                                    if (chkScroll.isChecked()) { // Scroll only if this is checked
                                        scrollView.post(new Runnable() { // Snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/1287554
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(loopDelay);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void stop() {
            bStop = true;
        }

    }

    private class DisConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (mReadThread != null) {
                mReadThread.stop();
                while (mReadThread.isRunning()); // Wait until it stops
                mReadThread = null;
            }

            try {
                mBTSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mIsBluetoothConnected = false;
            if (mIsUserInitiatedDisconnect) {
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mBTSocket != null && mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new DisConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
            new ConnectBT().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MonitoringScreen.this, "Bekleyiniz", "Bağlantı kuruluyor...");// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {

            try {
                if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                    mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    mBTSocket.connect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mConnectSuccessful = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cihaza bağlanılamadı. BT cihazınızı kontrol edin.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // durum.setText("Cihaza bağlanılamadı !");
                // durum.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#820000"));
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Cihaza bağlandı");
                mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
                mReadThread = new ReadInput(); // Kick off input reader
                // durum.setText("Bağlantı kuruldu")
                // durum.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0c7d00"));
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class ComunicaThread extends Thread{
        private  InputStream minputStream;
        private  OutputStream moutputStream;


        private ComunicaThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn= null;
            OutputStream tmpOut= null;

            try {

                tmpIn= socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut= socket.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d("eSocket","Error: " +e.toString());
            }
            this.minputStream= tmpIn;
            this.moutputStream= tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){

            byte[] buffer= new byte[1];
            while (true){
                Log.d("Run","Port serisinin girişini okuyan yöntem"  );
                try {
                    minputStream.read(buffer);
                    char ch=(char)buffer[0];
                    Log.d("Run","Port serisinin girişini okuyan yöntem:" +ch );

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }

        } }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            exitByBackKey();

            //moveTaskToBack(false);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    protected void exitByBackKey() {

        AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Uygulamadan çıkılsınmı ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        finish();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Hayır", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because data are receiving from BT in separate thread you must establish some inter-thread communication. For example check Bluetooth chat apk [here](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat).
Look on `Handler` in  `BluetoothChatFragment` class and also in `BluetoothChatService` class. Sending received char to UI thread you can see in `ConnectedThread` class in `run` method.